# SQLAlchemy how to recreate this update statement with the ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I’m trying to bulk-update a timestamp column on a model (Subscription) using an update statement.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```py
class Subscription(db.Model):
    id = db.Integer(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    locked_until = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.DateTime())
    failed_attempts = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=0, server_default="0")


temporary_error = []  # This is a list of Subscription instances
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
retry_delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds=600)
c_locked = Subscription.locked_until
c_attempts = Subscription.failed_attempts

Subscription.query.filter(cls.id.in_([s.id for s in temporary_error])).update({
    c_locked: func.pow(c_attempts, 2) * retry_delay + now,
    c_attempts: c_attempts + 1,
}, synchronize_session=False)
```

Using this Subscription.failed_attempts is incremented as expected, but `func.pow(c_attempts, 2) * retry_delay + now` seems to evaluate to just `now`.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Note: I’m actually using a TypeDecorator that converts to/from naive UTC datetime objects.

The (almost) equivalent Python code for this would be:

```py
for subscription in temporary_error:
    subscription.locked_until = 2 ** subscription.failed_attempts * retry_delay + now
    subscription.failed_attempts += 1
```

---

This is using SQLAlchemy 1.3.19 with PostgresSQL 12.5.